# Erro em acesso de membro de struct passada por referência

Tags: c, struct

Tenho o código abaixo que possui uma função para definir o salário = 4000, porém a mesma me retorna o seguinte erro:

> [Error] request for member 'salario' in something not a structure or union

O erro ocorre na linha que tento definir o salário.
Eu estou usando passagem de parâmetro por referencia, pois a passagem de parâmetro por valor não altera o salário do **Joao**, pois as alterações apenas ocorrem dentro da função, não se refletindo no salário dele.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    int idade;
    int salario;
}PESSOA;

void setSalario(PESSOA *p){
    *p.salario = 4000;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    PESSOA joao;

    setSalario(&joao);

    printf("Salario do joao: %d",joao.salario);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É uma mera questão de precedência de operadores. O operador `.` tem maior precedência sobre o `*` unário. Então:

```
*p.salario
```

É lido como:

```
*(p.salario)
```

E como `p` não é uma struct, é um ponteiro para uma, você não pode escrever `p.salario`.

Pode corrigir usando parenteses:

```
(*p).salario
```

Ou melhor, use o `->` para ler campos de um ponteiro para struct:

```
p->salario
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Guilherme

Comment: Bati o olho e já enxerguei, mas o Guilherme foi mais rápido ;p

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei o problema.

Na linha que defino o salário:

```
 *p.salario = 4000; // errado
(*p).salario = 4000; // correto
```